# Fullscreen canvas with jQuery buttons overlayed

Tags: css, html, jquery-ui, html5-canvas, webgl

I've been working on a webgl game and have full-screen toggle working for chrome and firefox. And I have been using dat.gui for a control input to this game. Which is based on jQuery-ui. In fact I can't get any child element to appear after fullscreen event has been fired. The behaviour is all the children get cleared,

```
:-webkit-full-screen {
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color:red;
} 


:-moz-full-screen body {
  width: 100% !important;
   background-color:red;
}

:full-screen body{
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color:red;
}

#navi {
    position:relative;
    right:10px;
    top:10px;
}
```

And these elements are used, where the canvas is dynamically created and appended to thegameCanvasDiv. While the dat.gui is appended to 'navi'.

```
<div id="gameCanvasDiv"></div>


<div id ="vSlider0"></div>
    <div id ="vSlider1"></div>

    <div id ="hSlider0"></div>

    <span id="navi" ></span>
```

Can I use the css to control the position a jQuery ui button after fullscreen?
I'm going round in circles here, so any suggests or insight would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make sure the elements you want to be visible is children of the `gameCanvasDiv` element (assuming that's the element you request full-screen mode at).

This means you need to put those sliders inside of that one. You can control their position using CSS as well as using JavaScript to set their position through their properties (ie. set a class when in full-screen, a different one when not - you'll get the idea).

By using z-index and absolute/fixed positions when full-screen can help you get them at top of the canvas element.

Be aware though that if you place elements on top of the canvas the performance of the canvas element is reduced.

Comment: I got this working. Took longer than I would have liked. But then I'm just learning CSS. I struggled placing the class selector in relations to the :-moz-full-screen selector (pseudo class?). A gui is required, so can't help but lose some performance there.

Comment: :-moz-full-screen canvas {} too access the canvas

:-moz-full-screen .gameGUI {} to access my gui class